# Troubles with the Fokker–Planck equation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations

I have read in several references that claims the following result: Given a 1-dimensional SDE
$$dX_t = a(X_t,t)dt + \sigma(X_t,t) dW_t $$
where $W_t$ is a brownian motion and $\alpha,\sigma:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ are smooth functions (with $\sigma>0$), then the Fokker-Plank equation
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}p(x,t) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(a(x,t)p(x,t)\right)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}\left(\sigma^2 (x,t) p(x,t)\right),$$
correspond to the equation of the density function of the solution of the SDE (for instance, on the Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation) it is possible to see this result).

I have seen several "derivations" of the Fokker-Plank equation (for instance in the book "Green functions for second-order parabolic integro-differential problems"- M.G. Garroni and J. L. Menaldi). My problem is that in all references that I have seen, they seem to start assuming that the measure
$$\mu(A) = \mathbb P(X_t\in A),$$
is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Therefore, my question is the following, is it possible for the inverse path? If $p$ satisfies the Fokker-Plank equation is it possible to show that $p$ is the probability density function o the SDE solution $X_t$?

A reference would be enough for me. All the best.

Comment: I would suggest you to read Section 5.1 in Karatzas & Shreve (1998): Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus.

Comment: Your questions (here and elsewhere) and my answers (here and elsewhere) are of course related. Take maybe a look also in Section 5.10 of the aforementioned reference, in particular the bibliographic remarks concerning Section 5.7.